# Как из json файла вывести только некоторые товары(не полностью весь массив)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html5

Делаю интернет магазин,используя json для вывода товаров в связке с javascript и jquery. В json у меня хранятся товары из одной категории,они выведены на страницу "женская спорт одежда".

Вопрос состоит в том,если я добавлю в этот же массив товары из всех категорий,с помощью какой функции я могу вывести только нужные товары на разных страницах категорий?

То есть как сделать выборку из json?нужен именно код выполняющий это,если это возможно.

Если этот метод неправильный,в таком случае лучше создать для каждой категории товаров свой json файл?

Вот часть json файла:

```
{
  "1234": {
  "name": "spodnie",
  "cost":60,
  "description": "spodnie bawelniane",
  "orer":1,
  "img":"leggins/50.jpg"
},
```

код функции нужен на javascript

Comment: json это всего лишь текстовое представление данных и не является альтернативой БД. Если вы хотите хранить данные (товары) в json файле, то придется выгружать файл на клиент целиком, парсить его в javascript массив и далее работать с массивом, выводя пользователю необходимую информацию. Предпочтительнее использовать базу данных, если вы хотите использовать javascript, то можно подключить node.js в связке с mongoDb.

Comment: @АлександрВеликий человек уже очевидно выгрузил файл куда надо, и спрашивает как отфильтровать. Если там все про все 20 товаров, то заводить БД возможно и не имеет смысла.

Comment: по какому полю фильтровать то собираетесь? у вас кстати, в коде приведен не массив, а объект с ключами.

Comment: @teran Совершенно верно,файл выгружен.Фильтровать нужно по id.

Comment: @АлександрВеликий    Мне не нужны объяснения что я должна делать с кодом и что бд лучше,это мне известно:)мне нужна функция фильтрации ,которая бы делала фильтрацию данного массива.

Comment: не стала показывать весь код массива,так как товары имеют одинаковые поля для всех категорий.не вижу смысла весь его выгружать,если нужно ,конечто могу предоставить

Comment: @Mariia Kramarenko, изучайте возможности языка. Функция для фильтрации массива уже давно придумана - Array.filter() называется.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Ну сделайте цикл с перебором элементов и выбирая нужные.

Comment: @Spomni Спасибо! думала эта функция не корректна в данном вопросе.вопрос исчерпан